# SQL statement to swap timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timestamp

I have several records that I have just copied and edited.

As you can tell in the following picture that I have 2 of each FactorType one with a timestamp of "2014...." and one with "2100..."

[image]

I just finished updating them to the values I wanted except I realized that I have the timestamps backwards. The records with the 2014 dates I want to have 2100 and the ones with the 2100, I want to have 2014.

Is there any series of SQL statements I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Just put everything in a temp table, setting your timestamps correctly.  Then reload your original table from the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

```
update e 
set     ValidTo = case  when e.ValidTo = '20140204' then '21000101' 
                        when e.ValidTo = '21000101' then '20140204' 
                    end
from    [central].dbo.EstimateFactors as e
where   [ComponentPart] = 'Labor Cost' and e.ValidTo in ('20140204','21000101')
```

**Edit**: Well ya, don't "test" code on your database.  Backup to another materialized table (`select * into EstimateFactors_backup from [central].dbo.EstimateFactors where [ComponentPart] = 'Labor Cost' and ValidTo in ('20140204','21000101')` might work, or just backup the db depending on what is appropriate).

Comment: I'd want to try this on test data first.  It may or may not work.

Comment: I thought about something like this, but I was afraid it would just end up setting the column to the same value all the way through.

Comment: Do the `select * into EstimateFactors_backup ...` that is in the Edit above, then do the update against that table first to see how it goes.